# Substring from very large text file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a very large text file (209 MB) with a large block of XML I'm trying to isolate. The text file is two different segments of XML and I want the second segment. Using PowerShell, I'm trying isolate from the beginning of what I want to the end using match, looking for a specific string that will always be at the beginning and end of the segment I want, it isn't working:

```
 $Hello = Get-Content "E:\sandbox\test.txt" 
 $Hello -match "</ns1:GetAllCompliancesResponse>(?<content>.*)</soapenv:Body>"
 $Hello = $Matches['content'] 
 $Hello | Out-File -FilePath "E:\sandbox\testoutput.txt"
```

I'm getting empty array errors when I run it in PS. I'm not quite sure where the problem might be.

Adding more after the great help I'm getting:

My data source is a 200mb file. Test parsing is an arduous process because of it's size. If my general structure is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:GetAllCompliancesResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://webservices.web.arber.arb.ca.gov">
     <GetAllCompliancesReturn soapenc:arrayType="ns2:ComplianceSummary[263026]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:ns2="urn:DrayageTruckStatusService" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <GetAllCompliancesReturn href="#id0"/>
        <GetAllCompliancesReturn href="#id1"/>
        <GetAllCompliancesReturn href="#id2"/>
        <GetAllCompliancesReturn href="#id3"/>
        <GetAllCompliancesReturn href="#id4"/>
        <GetAllCompliancesReturn href="#id263024"/>
        <GetAllCompliancesReturn href="#id263025"/>
     </GetAllCompliancesReturn>
  </ns1:GetAllCompliancesResponse>
     <multiRef id="id83299" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:ComplianceSummary" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns3="urn:TruckStatusService">
     <dtrNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">*********</dtrNumber>
     <licensePlateNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">*******</licensePlateNumber>
     <licensePlateState xsi:type="xsd:string">**</licensePlateState>
     <status xsi:type="xsd:string">************</status>
     <traceNumber xsi:type="xsd:int" xsi:nil="true"/>
     <untilDate xsi:type="xsd:date">***********</untilDate>
     <vin xsi:type="xsd:string">**********************</vin>
  </multiRef>
  <multiRef id="id132635" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns4:ComplianceSummary" xmlns:ns4="urn:TruckStatusService" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <dtrNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">*********</dtrNumber>
     <licensePlateNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">*******</licensePlateNumber>
     <licensePlateState xsi:type="xsd:string">**</licensePlateState>
     <status xsi:type="xsd:string">***********</status>
     <traceNumber xsi:type="xsd:int" xsi:nil="true"/>
     <untilDate xsi:type="xsd:date">***********</untilDate>
     <vin xsi:type="xsd:string">**********************</vin>
   </multiRef>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How would I form the XPath to get the items in the multiRef nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A successful `-match` only populates `$Matches` when used in *scalar mode* (i.e. when the left-hand side operand is a single object), it doesn't work when you use `-match` to filter a collection.

```
$Hello = Get-Content "E:\sandbox\test.txt" |ForEach-Object {
  if($_ -match "</ns1:GetAllCompliancesResponse>(?<content>.*)</soapenv:Body>"){
    $Matches['content']
  }
}

$Hello | Out-File -FilePath "E:\sandbox\testoutput.txt"
```

This approach will only work if the entire string is on one line.

---

Given that the content is XML, I would rather suggest using some of the excellent XML parsing tools available in PowerShell instead of regular expressions.

Assuming you want all sibling nodes following `</ns1:GetAllCompliancesResponse>`, you could probably do something like:

```
$Content = Get-Content .\big.xml |Select-Xml -XPath '//*[local-name() = "GetAllCompliancesResponse"]' |ForEach-Object {
  $node = $_.Node
  while($node = $node.NextSibling){
    $node.OuterXml # output current node markup as text
  }
}

$Content |Out-File .\output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using Select-Xml -XPath //multiRef and I'm getting Error: "'soapenv' is an undeclared prefix.

My file is coming from a WSDL endpoint. Do I need to put an XML declaration at the top?

Comment: Either add a declaration with namespace prefixes declared, or pass a hashtable to `Select-Xml -Namespace @{ soapenv = "schema URI goes here" }`

Comment: I'm going to update my post to show my data structure. Could you please assist with the Xpath/namespace? You're really teaching me the tools I need here. Thanks.

Comment: @alcor8 Not really sure why you're getting the error you mentioned - the sample document you added to the post has correct ns declaration and I can parse it with `Select-Xml` just fine :-/

Comment: @alcor8: I suggest reverting the question edit, accepting an answer based on the question _as originally asked_ (Mathias' answer seems appropriate) and then asking a _new_, focused question to address your namespace / XPath problems.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64897861/45375):

Assuming that regex-based, line-by-line plain-text processing is possible (**based on your later update, it *isn't* possible**; also, as stated in Mathias' answer, using XML parsing is generally preferable):

An efficient way to process files line by line is the [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch), whose `-Regex` option also populates the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches):

```
Set-Content E:\sandbox\testoutput.txt -Encoding utf8 -Value $(
  switch -Regex -File E:\sandbox\test.txt {
    '</ns1:GetAllCompliancesResponse>(?<content>.*)</soapenv:Body>' {
      $Matches.content
    }
  }
)
```

Note the use of `-Value` to pass the file content to `Set-Content`, which is much faster than supplying the content via the *pipeline*; while the use of `-Value` requires collecting all content in memory first, that shouldn't be a problem in your case.